# how to compare date with GETDATE() in sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, which is used to insert some kind of information to table 'demotable', in that i have a field loginTime where datatype is dateTime.
i am using GETDATE() to get the current datetime, problem is i want to compare whether this GETDATE() is lower than 9:00 AM and then make it as 9:00AM, if not lower keep the output as it is without any changes. -using microsoft sql server 2008.

below is my sample stored procedure

```
         //Beg Stored Procedure Contents...


            insert into dbo.demoTable([loginTime],[nStatus]) values(GETDATE(),'1')

         //End
```

Comment: Google is your friend. It's so easy to search for how to perform date comparisons. Clearly by the lack of code shown, you just want someone to come along and write your program for you and that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: You are inserting into database so in c# use DataTime methods to do conversion before storing into database.  You code is not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Should work on 2008 and above

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR,GETDATE()) < 9 THEN DATEADD(HOUR,9,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) ELSE GetDate() END

Answer (score 0):

This query will check if the current time is before 9:00 AM, if no, it will keep whatever is the result of calling `getdate()`. Otherwise, it will make it 9:00 AM.

```
select iif(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 9, 
           dateadd(hh, 9,  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),
           getdate())
```

Comment: i want to keep the time as it is when its 9:00Am or Above, if its lower than 9:00 make it as 9:00AM, and what is this `select iff` - im using sql server 2008, and it supports IIF ?

Comment: Yes that is what it will do. Small typo in my answer. I should have written *if no* but I wrote *if yes*.

Answer (score 0):

`select CASE when DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()) < 9 THEN dateadd(hh, 9,  DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) ELSE getdate() END`

This is the solution that i have founnd myself, Thanks @CodingYoshi for your tip, Where SQL Server 2008 Does Not support IIF, Instead we can use CASE